# Find and count occurences of a substring of table1 in table2 and have a result group by another column of table2

Tags: mysql

I have a table1

```
| id | mystring
|----|--------------------|
|1   |value1-value2-value4|
|2   |value2-value3       |
|3   |value3-value4-value5|
```

than the table2

```
| id |type  | name | cat|
|----|------|------|----|
|1   |type1 |value1|cat1|
|2   |type1 |value2|cat1|
|3   |type1 |value3|cat1|
|4   |type1 |value4|cat2|
|5   |type2 |value5|cat3|
```

then I want this result

```
|cat |count|
|----|-----|
|cat1|5    |
|cat2|2    |
```

I search a lot on and the best I manage to do is

```
SELECT cat,name,
      (SELECT ROUND((SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(mystring)) -
                SUM(CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(mystring, name, ''))))
               / CHAR_LENGTH(name)) FROM table1 AS occurrence_count
FROM table2 GROUP BY name,cat having occurrence_count>0
```

but the result is

```
|name  |cat |count|
|------|----|-----|
|value1|cat1|1    |
|value2|cat1|2    |
|value3|cat1|2    |
|value4|cat2|2    |
```

**But I want it to be group by cat only and have the sum of all the values in the same categories.**
Ih I delete "name" in the GROUP BY, The count is false because the result just forget the 2 last rows.  So please can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably write this query using a join approach:

```sql
SELECT t2.cat, COUNT(t1.id) AS occurrence_count
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON CONCAT('-', t1.mystring, '-') LIKE CONCAT('%-', t2.name, '-%')
GROUP BY t2.cat;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you very very very much. Your query solved my problem.